# Changing public variable for all objects the script is attached to in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have 2 scripts. One changes a public variable on the conditions by another script. I want a public variable to change for all the objects the second script is attached to. But the variable changes only for the object that is referred to by the first script. I also don't know how to refer a script instead of an object to the first one. I don't have any local variables that have the same name as the public one.

How do I make the variable change for all objects or attach a script instead of an object?

I am programming in C# btw.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the [`static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static) is for.

Let's say e.g. you have a field

```c#
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int SomeStaticInt;
}
```

then this field is now not anymore a member of the instance(s) of `Example` but rather a direct [static member](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members#static-members) of that type itself.

This means that there is only one single field and you access it from just anywhere using e.g.

```c#
Example.SomeStaticInt--;
if(Example.SomeStaticInt < 0)
{
    Example.SomeStaticInt = 10;
}
```

within the `Example` class the `Example.` is of course redundant and internally you simply access the field as you used to before.